# How to make bootstrap form filed to 100 percent in width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two col divs in a row with each having two text filed while re-sizing in mobile the width of the textbox is not going to 100% and looking ugly.

Below is my bootstrap code, but in select filed the width is looks OK ..

here is the demo link see the 'Name' and 'Phone' field

http://www.responsinator.com/?url=webapplications.co.in%2Fdiamovitcarhire.com%2Fget-a-quote.html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-lg-6" >
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="Name">Name </label>
          <div class="input-group">
            <input class="input-md form-control" name="Name" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="phone">Phone </label>
          <div class="input-group">
            <input class="input-md form-control" name="phone" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: remove `<div class="input-group">`

Comment: ok I removed but its disturbing the start date and end date filed and both were not going to 100% fit

Comment: please follow this HTML structure https://jsfiddle.net/1kLh0op1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably want is something like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6" >
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Name">Name </label>
                <input class="form-control" name="Name" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="phone">Phone </label>
                <input class="form-control" name="phone" type="tel">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you use that structure it should work like you described it.

Answer (score -1):

Most likely you are using 'container' as your base. According to Bootstrap's [site](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) (search for 'container-fluid') the container-fluid class is the one setting div to full width of your viewport.

Comment: Did you even look at the website or did you just copy and paste your answer after reading "bootstrap" and "full width"?

Comment: Haven't any previous answers to copy from - the full width divs were problem I had with leaning bootstrap not so long ago, so wanted to check that.